# How to replace javascript with javascript without a variable </script> tag ending the javascript early in firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace some javascript code with some generated/created by some other javascript...

It's only really for debugging purposes, not supposed to do anything per se.

```
                // Create variable containing js code
                var jsCode = '<script type="text/javascript">'
                jsCode  += 'window.website.load("MainFunction", function(var1, var2, var3, var4) {'
                jsCode += ' var1({'
                jsCode += '     location: "useast"'
                jsCode += ' });'
                jsCode += '});'
                jsCode += '</script>'

                // Update js code
                $('#jsCode').replaceWith('<div id="jsCode">' + jsCode + '</div>');
```

**I do need it to keep the formatting of whitespace.**

It works perfectly in Chrome as it detects that the  tag is inside of a variable but in Firefox it doesn't detect it and ends the javascript early.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Does Firefox keep the whitespace?

Comment: @Nicholas Firefox gets completely messed up

Comment: Does it throw an error? Can you show us what the script looks like in Firefox?

Comment: @Nicholas It ends the script early, it thinks that the script inside `jsCode += '</script>'` is the end of the script, so everything after that is just put into the page as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using backticks for a multiline string instead of +=?

```js
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML=`
alert('hi');
console.log('hi');
`;

//will say hi, bu then will alert the innerHTML of the script showing whitespace preserved (tested in FIrefox)
document.body.appendChild(script);
alert(script.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the modern way to inject dynamic script into a document. Instead, use the DOM API. Here's an example:

```js
// We won't be parsing strings of HTML to make this work.
// Instead, we'll create a new <script> element and inject
// that into the DOM
var newScript = document.createElement("script");

// Again, we'll be working with elements/nodes, not strings to be parsed
var inlineScript = document.createTextNode("alert('Hello World!');");

// The nodes will be built up into a single node
newScript.appendChild(inlineScript); 

// And, then the script node will be injected into the existing DOM
document.head.appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: That doesn't keep the whitespace formatting though... which is what I am wanting.

Comment: I understand that you would "like" the white space, but to make this work in all clients, you have to do it this way.

Comment: @Scott_Marcus If that's true then, I could do with some help understanding how to add the lines of my code into this inline script text node.

Comment: @Ryflex What help do you need? You can create one text node that contains all your script commands or you can create several (one for each command) as I've shown above.